# File checking for username and password

Tags: java, input, jquery-ui-dialog, java.util.scanner

I have created a Java program that reads a .txt file that has two strings per name.

Rob Junior

Bobby Kelly

When it reads it and does not find the associated name, it will show a dialog error message. The problem I'm running into is the program is reading every line and will display a error message for every line if it does not match. Here is a fragment of my code:

```
  Scanner fileScan = new Scanner (new File("1.txt"));
  while (fileScan.hasNextLine()){
      String input = fileScan.nextLine();
      String Username = input.substring(0,input.indexOf(' '));
      String Password = input.substring(input.indexOf(' '),input.length());

      if (Username.equals(inputusername) || (Password.equals(inputpassword)))
      {
          getContentPane().removeAll();
          getContentPane().add(panel3);//Adding to content pane, not to Frame
          repaint();
          printAll(getGraphics());
      } 
      else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Invalid password. Try again.",
                "Error Message",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      }
  }
```

`inputusername` and `inputpassword` were strings that read a text field in my program. I know I should probably be using something other than a while loop but can't seem to piece it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is move the check to see if the password is not in the file outside the while loop. The following code does this by setting a temporary variable to false, and then setting it to true if the username and password combination were found. Otherwise, it remains false and after checking the file, we display the dialog error.

```
  Scanner fileScan = new Scanner (new File("1.txt"));
  boolean found = false; // added this variable
  while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
    String input = fileScan.nextLine();
    String Username = input.substring(0,input.indexOf(' '));
    String Password = input.substring(input.indexOf(' '),input.length());

    if (Username.equals(inputusername) || (Password.equals(inputpassword))) {
      found = true; // added this to set found
      getContentPane().removeAll();
      getContentPane().add(panel3);//Adding to content pane, not to Frame
      repaint();
      printAll(getGraphics());
    } // removed the else statement
  }

  if(!found) { // added the contents of the previously existing else statement here, outside the while
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
      "Invalid password. Try again.",
      "Error Message",
      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you... I can't believe I stressed over this for that long @Bucco

Comment: K_Kong, no problem, I'm glad I could help - once I never defined a variable and kept wondering why it wasn't compiling, you can imagine my frustration when I figured out why.

Comment: @peeskillet got it! I definitely understand, just seeing that all i needed was a boolean and a few brackets makes that hour of figuring it out all to waste...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("1.txt"));
    boolean founduser = false;
    while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        String input = fileScan.nextLine();
        String Username = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
        String Password = input.substring(input.indexOf(' '), input.length());

        if (Username.equals(inputusername) && (Password.equals(inputpassword))) {
            founduser = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (founduser) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add(panel3);// Adding to content pane, not to Frame
        repaint();
        printAll(getGraphics());
    }

    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid password. Try again.", "Error Message",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileReading {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner (new File("test.txt"));
      boolean found = false; // added this variable
      while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        String input = fileScan.nextLine();
        String Username = input.substring(0,input.indexOf(' '));
        String Password = input.substring(input.indexOf(' ')+1,input.length());


        if ((Username.equals("pawan")) && (Password.equals("kalyan"))) {
          found = true; // added this to set found
          System.out.println("Success");

        } 
      }

      if(!found) { 
        System.out.println("failed");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the  solution to your problem

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Credentials {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    System.out.println("Enter user name");
    String inputUser = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Password");
    String inputPassword = br.readLine();

    Credentials c =new Credentials();
    c.readPassword(inputUser,inputPassword );
}

void readPassword(String inputUser,String inputPassword) throws Exception {
   Scanner scr = new Scanner(new File("password.txt"));
   boolean flag=false;
   while(scr.hasNextLine()){
   String line = scr.nextLine();
   String username= line.substring(0,line.indexOf(' '));
   String password =line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1,line.length());
       System.out.println(username+","+password);

   if(inputUser.endsWith(username) && inputPassword.equals(password) ){
       System.out.println("Valid user");
       flag=true;
       break;
   }

   }
   if(!flag){
       System.out.println("invalid user");
   }
}
```

}